# Migrate background task to azure cloud

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, background-task, paas

Currently, we have a VM where Windows Scheduler is used to execute the console app with the argument. For each schedule frequency, a different value is passed as an argument.

Is it possible to move this background task to Azure Cloud (PaaS) so as not to become attached to SDK? If so, what services could be used?

I researched Azure Functions, but it allows only a single time trigger for the function, and we do not want to modify codebase of the old app.

Comment: What does the schedule frequency looks like? How many different arguments?

Comment: *we do not want to modify codebase of the old app*. Then you're not going to be able to turn it into a native PaaS service.

Comment: @DennisRongo single string parameter. frequency: once a day (param value 1), once a week (param value 2) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this will work so you will have to try it but here is what I am thinking.  If you can get your Scheduled task to run in a Windows Container ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085081/error-trying-to-create-a-scheduled-task-within-windows-2016-core-container)) then you can run that container in an Azure App Service.  Windows container support is in preview.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container